# Search works in Search Center, but not in local sites - any more

Tags: search

Enterprise and SharePoint searches work perfectly in the search center site, but not in local sites anymore. They used to work on local sites, until shortly after we created a search center site to show enterprise results. I am not sure if these are connected issues.

I have looked all over for an answer. Some mention problems with search scopes on sites, etc, but we didn't change anything. It just stopped working on local sites by itself.

Logs were inconclusive as far as we can read them. We do not have Fast Search.

Comment: Yes you changing the Search Center (in this creation of a new one) is connected to your search working on your site/site collections. What webdes03 has said is exactly what you should be looking at. You need to update your search center settings on all of your site collections.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated all of your site collections search configuration to use the scopes of the search center? Have you set the site collection search configurations to use the results page in the search center?

Can you give us an overview of the actual errors? "Search doesn't work" doesn't give us a lot to go on...